# ionic build android FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cradle

I created an Android platform with success, but when I run 
ionic build android 
I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/skylek/Ionic/conFusion/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/skylek/Ionic/conFusion/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/skylek/Ionic/conFusion/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/skylek/Ionic/conFusion/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with an ionic project build  with the m-ionic yeoman generator, that was uploaded to the ionic cloud.

It started after my computer crashed with a 'blue screen of death',  in the middle of a compilation task

What We did to fix the project was to copy and replacing the gradle and corodova files :

- .gradle
- cordova
- CordovaLib
- gradle
- gradlew.bat

from other ionic>platform>android  project that I knew was working fine, beacuse we thought the Cordova files might be corrupted, and early in the project  we fixed a similar compilation problem that way. It did not fixed the problem. But then removed the ionic cloud configuration files:  ionic.project .

And it worked!!

I hope it could help you!